# Get tweet from the user?

Tags: objective-c, tweets

What is the best way to get twitts from the user on iPhone. Is it possible to get twitts with help of search twitter API? [twitter search api doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)
I need load more than 20 twitts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweets are returned from Twitter's servers in JSON format. There are a half-dozen JSON libraries for cocoa, all very good.

Fetching tweets can be done using a simple URL request, for unauthenticated tweet data (e.g. users tweets are public). e.g. http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=sn00ki&include_entities=true

Or if you need access to tweets that might be private, you are going to have to log in, probably using OAuth. I would suggest a twitter library. MGTwitterEngine, for example.

If you can go iOS 5 only, you can use the new built in [Twitter Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011014)